# Problem using Managed C++ (.Net 2.0) in .Net 2.0 project in VS2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have two projects:

1) a project written in Visual C++ 2005 which targets the .net Framework 2.0.

2) a project in Visual C# 2010 that targets .net framework 2.0 and includes the C++ DLL.

When I build the C# project referencing the C++ assembly, I get errors like:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "ScannerWizard" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "ScannerWizard" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "ScannerWizard" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "ScannerWizard" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "ScannerWizard" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "ScannerWizard" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "System.Data.SqlXml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
```

If I make the project 4.0, it doesn't give those errors. Obviously, I shouldn't have to make it target 4.0 to use a 2.0 assembly.

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you convert the C++/CLI project?  Don't, only add the reference.

Comment: Nope, the ScanWizard DLL was last compiled 4 years ago, in Visual C++ 2005. It hasn't been recompiled or anything. It shouldn't need to be either, but if there's something I can do differently when I compile it I gladly will.

Comment: By using ILSpy, I was able to find that the VC++ DLL has a reference to MFCMIFC80, which depends on mscorlib and System. Rather than using the 2.0 version, it's using the latest version on the system, which is 4.0. There must be a way to prevent it from doing this?

Comment: The warnings cause the objects exposed via that DLL to not be available.

Comment: Fix: Deleting MFCMIFC80.DLL from the machine fixes the issue.

Comment: Furthermore, other machines, that don't have the .net 4.0 framework, don't have that DLL present. I checked one of our build servers that does all the installation building and found that DLL didn't even exist on that machine anywhere, in the GAC, etc. So, I'd say anyone running into this problem should definitely try renaming/moving/deleting that file and see if that fixes the problem. I'm sure something in 4.0 depends on it, but at this point, I don't care, as I'm only worried about 2.0 development.

Comment: Deleting the DLL seems like a pretty high-risk way of fixing your problem (successful though it is).  Perhaps [FuslogVW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx) would let you figure out the chain of assemblies being loaded and that in turn might let you [write a policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) to redirect to the 2.0 assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ project was using the v100 Platform toolset. This makes it depend on 4.0 .NET versions of some libraries. Changing the toolset to v90 solves the problem. You may need to install the v90 toolset if you don't have them...