# Problem using Managed C++ (.Net 2.0) in .Net 2.0 project in VS2010. Referencing 4.0 .NET functionalities

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-2.0, c++-cli

I have exactly the same problem asked here.

[Problem using Managed C++ (.Net 2.0) in .Net 2.0 project in VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457541/problem-using-managed-c-net-2-0-in-net-2-0-project-in-vs2010).

Basically I have a C++/CLI project in .NET 2.0 and it indirectly references some 4.0 version dll via MFCMIFC80.DLL.

The only solution the person found was to delete MFCMIFC80.DLL.

How safe is that? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

The C++ project was using the v100 Platform toolset. This makes it depend on 4.0 .NET versions of some libraries.
Changing the toolset to v90 solves the problem.